# Scala, ClassTag and Guice: Error injecting constructor, java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, reflection, playframework, guice, classtag

In my Play 2 application, I need to create a class tag in the class which is instantiated by Guice (as an eager singleton; this is a requirement).

```
case class UserCreated(id: Long, userName: String) extends ApplicationEvent

@Singleton
class AccountRoleUpdater @Inject()
    (accountRepository: AccountRepository)
    (implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem, ec: ExecutionContext) {

    implicit def ct: ClassTag[UserCreated] = classTag[UserCreated]

    // THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR       
    val cls = ct.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[UserCreated]]     
}
```

Here is the Guice binding:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
    bind(classOf[account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater]).asEagerSingleton()
}
```

When the application starts, I'm getting the following exception:

> CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:45)
>   at Module.configure(Module.scala:64) (via modules:
>   com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> Module)   while
>   locating account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater
>
> 1 error]  at
>   play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:186)
>     at
>   play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
>     at
>   play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.modelConversion(AkkaHttpServer.scala:183)
>     at
>   play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
>     at
>   play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$3(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
>     at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$23.onPush(Ops.scala:1172)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:499)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:462)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:368)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:571)
>   Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create
>   injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:45)
>   at Module.configure(Module.scala:64) (via modules:
>   com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> Module)   while
>   locating account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater
>
> 1 error   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:470)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:184)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
>     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)    at
>   com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)     at
>   play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:185)
>     at
>   play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
>     at
>   play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
>     at
>   play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$reload$3(DevServerStart.scala:174)
>     at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
>   Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)
>     at
>   account.eventlistener.AccountRoleUpdater.ct(AccountRoleUpdater.scala:21)

It seems to be a cyclical reference.

Comment: do you need `cls` to be a `val`? Not sure what happens but it could help to turn it into a `def`...

Comment: Why is `ct` an `implicit def`? Isn't `implicit def` used for converting/wrapping types? I'd first try to make it `val`, then try to remove the `implicit` if that doesn't work...

Comment: val does not work either.